# How to unassign a value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a table similar to the following

**id | name | address**

both **name and address** are not nullable(this i achieve through attribute setters only and not by default)

When i create a new record without any default values what will be stored in the table?

If the value is null
 
    -> if i store a value (say name="MyName", address="The address"). can i reset it back to null at if needed? I cannot assign null here since my setter wont allow.

In short - **can i unassign a value stored in a record's field using something like**

```
my_object.name.delete
```

from my controller?

Thanks you

**Update-the model setter**

```
def name=(value)
  if name.nil? raise "Can't be nil" 
end
```

Comment: You might want to insert the model code to be clearer.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? If you want null/empty values then remove the check from the setter. The "Rails Way" to implement this kind of validation is to use an ActiveRecord validator. This would allow different behaviour on create and update which I guess may be the root of the issue you are trying to resolve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can. But first, my assumptions:

1. I'm going to assume that you are using `ActiveRecord` and you have a model called `MyModel` in order to treat that table.
2. I'm going to assume that you used the proper way to make fields non-nullable, which is by using validations. If this is not the case, I strongly suggest that you reconsider using them.

Then you can do:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_pressence_of :name, :if => :check_name

  attr_writer :check_name
  def check_name # make it defalt to true
    @check_name = @check_name.nil? ? true : @check_name
  end
end
```

You can use it like this:

```
my_object.name = "Josh"
my_object.save # ok
my_object.name = ""
my_object.save # not ok
my_object.check_name = false
my_object.save # ok
```

Comment: When assigning my_object.name, can you give it a nil?  At the DB level, there is a difference between a NULL column and a column with an empty string, I think.

Comment: At the db level there is, but validates_presence_of is intelligent enough not to be fooled by an empty string. It will bark if you try to put any "non-empty" value on the name - a nil, an empty string, or an empty array if I remember correctly.